# Azure APIM Unexpected response body when rate-limit-by-key is triggered

Tags: azure-api-management

I have a policy in my APIM for throttling calls to an endpoint when a header called "client-id" calls the endpoint more than two times in a minute.
The throttling part works fine, but the response body when the limit is hit is not what I expected.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/65576593/22934799 I would expect the response body to be a json with a status code and a message but what I get is an html with HTTP 403 Forbidden:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Request Rejected</title>
</head>

<body>The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your
    administrator.<br><br>Your support ID is: 11411346622183591440</body>
</html>
```

What is happening here? Getting an HTML back is not very clean for an API.

The policy in question.

```
<rate-limit-by-key calls="2"
            renewal-period="60"
            counter-key="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("client-id",""))"
/>
```

I also tried putting the policy on the Echo API (has no other policies that could interfere) in the APIM web and hitting it until the limit triggered but then it just gives me a warning notification saying "Could not complete the request. Please try again later." which is not really helpful as it gives no http code or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get the expected response for `rate-limit-by-key` policy  when the defined limit exceeds.

I am using this policy in the Echo API.

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <rate-limit-by-key calls="2" renewal-period="60" counter-key="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("client-id",""))" />
    </inbound>
</policies>
```

**Testing**-

[image]
[image]

When limit call exceeds, I am getting below response

[image]

> it just gives me a warning notification saying "Could not complete the request. Please try again later." which is not really helpful as it gives no http code or anything.

Try to refresh/load the page and check, I believe you will get the result too or else you can create a new APIM instance and try. If your issue still persists, I would suggest you to check with the product team.

Comment: Yes, I think it's most likely something with our instance.